# How to match something like shortcode that repeats and contains whatever including new lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback, non-greedy

I am trying to process something similar like shrotcode via preg_replace_callback function:

```
$new_content = preg_replace_callback("|\[BLOCK\s?(TYPE=[0-9a-z\/]+)?\s?(TEXT=[a-z]+)?\s?(LAST)?\s?\]((?:(?!BLOCK).)*)\[\/BLOCK\]|","block",$content);
```

The subject ($content) is for example this:

```
[BLOCK TYPE=1/2 TEXT=right LAST]
<ul><li>something</li>
</ul>
[/BLOCK]
[BLOCK TYPE=1/2 TEXT=right LAST][NEXTSHORTCODE=something][/BLOCK]
[BLOCK TYPE=1/2 TEXT=right LAST]123[/BLOCK]
```

I met a problem:

Function preg_replace_callback matches whole subject (from BLOCK to last /BLOCK) instead of first occurance of /BLOCK.
I wanted to solve it excluding string BLOCK ((?:(?!BLOCK).)*) from inner content of a shortcode but it do not work with other characters like new line etc.

You can see my tries here: http://rubular.com/r/0AqadXVdON

Thank you for advise and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a so-called lazy match expression for your closing tag.

Your regex ends with `\[\/BLOCK\]`.

Try ending it with `\[\/BLOCK\]?` instead. That will make it match the first occurrence it finds (lazy) rather than the last occurrence(greedy).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Ollie said, if you don't care about the TYPE and other references inside a BLOCK and just want to replace all blocks, you could go with something as simple as:

```
$regex = "~(?s)\[BLOCK.*?/BLOCK]~";
$new_content = preg_replace_callback($regex, $block, $subject);
function block($m) {
  // replace magic
  return $something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `m` switch.

Try this on instead:

`\[BLOCK\s?(TYPE=[0-9a-z\/]+)?\s?(TEXT=[a-z]+)?\s?(LAST)?\s?\]((?:(?!BLOCK).)*)\[\/BLOCK\]`

Demo

http://rubular.com/r/7ijXdrhERE